# Compile Warnings while writing File, whats wrong?

Tags: c, fopen, compiler-warnings

I'm getting these compile warnings in my function and can't find any errors on my code:

warnings:

```
src.c: In function ‘writeFiles’:
src.c:119:18: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
src.c:119:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:269:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

my function:

```
FILE *outfile;
int writeFiles(int pwm, int rpm)
{

    outfile = fopen('/dev/fan/rpm', "w+");  /* line 119 with the warnings */ /*create the new file */ 
    fprintf(outfile, "%d", rpm);            /*write the rpm to the file */
    fclose(outfile);                        /*close the file */

    return ( 0 );

}
```

I hope you can help me to get this fixed. neither google nor stackoverflow could help finding a solution for this problems.

Comment: Can you mark the line numbers giving warnings in your code snippet? Also `fopen` takes a char* as first parameter, why are your delimiters single quotes?

Comment: `'` characters are your problem. Use single quotes for individual characters only. Use double quotes for strings.

Comment: `'/dev/fan/rpm'` ---> `"/dev/fan/rpm"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is happening because `fopen` takes a char* as parameter but you're passing it a (*too long*) char.

Replace `fopen('/dev/fan/rpm', "w+")` by `fopen("/dev/fan/rpm", "w+")`. *Double* quotes.

Comment: thank you, this fixed it, i'll accept your answer as soon as i'm able too. ( 9 minutes )

Comment: Good to hear it's fixed :)

Comment: Actually, he's passing an `int`, not a `char`. The type of integer character constants like `'a'` or `'foo'` is `int`.

Comment: Agreed, that's what the 2nd warning is saying.

Comment: It's the note (third line) that's saying that, "integer" can also be a `char` or `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan points out your filename is actually a `char` with too many characters. It explains both warnings and the note.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need double quotes around the filenames in the fopen calls.

e.g.

```
outfile = fopen("/dev/fan/rpm", "w+");
```